# How to Generate MySQL Procedure to get Date between a date range incremented by 1 month until ending date

Tags: mysql

I have a joined table containing some data including `p_id`, `starts_on` and `ends_on`. I want to increment `starts_on` by 1 month til `ends_on` for each `p_id`.

So, the table I have looks like;

```
p_id    starts_on    ends_on
-----------------------------
1      2018-01-01   2018-12-31
2      2018-05-03   2018-12-31
3      2018-06-01   2018-07-30
```

What I want to do is like;

```
p_id    starts_on    ends_on
-----------------------------
1      2018-01-01   2018-12-31
1      2018-02-01   2018-12-31
1      2018-03-01   2018-12-31
.       .            .
.       .            .
1      2018-11-01   2018-12-31
1      2018-12-01   2018-12-31
2      2018-05-03   2018-12-31
2      2018-06-03   2018-12-31
.       .            .
.       .            .
2      2018-12-03   2018-12-31
3      2018-06-01   2018-07-30
```

and so on.

So, is there any way to do it? I looked up to just increment date, but I need to increment it depending on p_id as well

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code. Otherwise, specify which version of MySQL you're using.

Comment: It is MySQL 8.0

Comment: Seems you have not provided enough information about your data and why you're trying to do this. Notice how redundant the date columns are, `p_id` should also be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cursor for this:

```
create procedure sp_pids_expand()
begin
declare done int default 0;
declare v_p_id int;
declare v_starts_on date;
declare v_ends_on date;
declare v_newday date;
declare v_cnt int;

declare c_pids cursor for
  select p_id, starts_on, ends_on
  from pids
  where date_add(starts_on, interval 1 month)<ends_on;

declare continue handler for not found set done = 1;

open c_pids;
repeat
  fetch c_pids into v_p_id, v_starts_on, v_ends_on;

  if not done then
    set v_newday = v_starts_on;
    while (date_add(v_newday, interval 1 month)<v_ends_on) do

      set v_newday = date_add(v_newday, interval 1 month);

      select count(*) into v_cnt
      from pids
      where p_id=v_p_id and starts_on=v_newday and ends_on=v_ends_on;

      if (v_cnt=0) then
        insert into pids (p_id, starts_on, ends_on)
        values (v_p_id, v_newday, v_ends_on);
      end if;      
    end while;

  end if;
until done end repeat;

close c_pids;

end
```